# dplyr mutate_each_ standard evaluation

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm racking my brain over the SE implementation of mutate_each_ in dplyr. What I want to do is to subtract the value in one column in a DF from every column in the DF.

Here is a minimum working example of what I'm looking to accomplish, using the iris dataset (I remove the 'Species' column so that it is all numeric). I subtract the Petal.Width column from every column. But I need the column name to be a variable, such as "My.Petal.Width"

```
# Remove Species column, so that we have only numeric data
iris_numeric <- iris %>% select(-Species)

# This is the desired result, using NSE
result_NSE <- iris_numeric %>% mutate_each(funs(. - `Petal.Width`))

# This is my attempt at using SE 
SubtractCol <- "Petal.Width"
result_SE <- iris_numeric %>% mutate_each_(funs(. - as.name(SubtractCol)))

# Second attempt
SubtractCol <- "Petal.Width"
Columns <- colnames(iris_numeric)
mutate_call = lazyeval::interp(~.-a, a = as.name(SubtractCol))
result_SE <- iris_numeric %>% mutate_each_(.dots = setNames(list(mutate_call), Columns))
```

I get various errors:

```
Error in colwise_(tbl, funs_(funs), vars) : 
  argument "vars" is missing, with no default

Error in mutate_each_(., .dots = setNames(list(mutate_call), Columns)) : 
  unused argument (.dots = setNames(list(mutate_call), Columns))
```

Please help and many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking for is the SE version of `funs`, i.e. `funs_`:

```
library(lazyeval); library(dplyr)
SubtractCol <- "Petal.Width"
iris %>% mutate_each(funs_(interp(~.-x, x = as.name(SubtractCol))), -Species) %>% head
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1          4.9         3.3          1.2           0  setosa
#2          4.7         2.8          1.2           0  setosa
#3          4.5         3.0          1.1           0  setosa
#4          4.4         2.9          1.3           0  setosa
#5          4.8         3.4          1.2           0  setosa
#6          5.0         3.5          1.3           0  setosa
```

You would use `mutate_each_` if you wanted to supply what I wrote as "-Species" as a string/variable.

Note that there's no `.dots` argument in `mutate_each_` and `summarise_each_`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
result_SE <- iris_numeric %>% 
mutate_each_(funs(paste0('. - ',as.name(SubtractCol)))
```

as there should be `character` specified, not the formula with a fragment of a character

Comment: Hi Marcin - thanks for your comment, however I still get the "vars" is missing error. (ps - a small typo in your code: pate0 vs paste0)